# How do I avoid falling into pitfalls underground?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When mining, I always seem to fall into precarious pitfalls in the underground.  How do I prevent myself from falling down into danger and losing all of my progress? And ther also are abandoned mineshafts caves and ravines but I would like too know a seed with a stronghold above ground too thanks

Comment: Look before you leap?

Comment: rule number 1 of minecraft: don't mine the block you are standing on

Comment: Strongholds do not appear above ground.

Comment: This is at least two questions in one.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the most obvious answer is to place lots and lots of torches.  If you can *see* the pitfall coming, it shouldn't be a problem for you, as you can prepare yourself ahead of time.

Traversing a pitfall, IE getting across it, can be a bit trickier.  If you have a nearby ledge you can place blocks on, you can take a stack of dirt and build yourself a quick bridge across, block-by-block, without having to worry about falling in.  You should probably make it 2x wide if you are worried, and be careful of any low-hanging blocks.

If you want to get down into the pit, the safest way is to just dig down.  Estimate about how many blocks you need to dig, then dig into a wall (or just down into the floor) Until you reach that far.  Be careful coming out, as a pitfall can be deeper than you realized.

Comment: And remember to sneak (default key: Shift). While sneaking, you do not fall off blocks.

Comment: Important note! Armor doesn't absorb fall damage anymore. Only enchantments do.

Comment: Since this question is closed, I won't edit this in, but this is ALSO important: Never dig straight down.  Not even at the edge of a pitfall.  You never know when the edge might bevel in, and leave you digging into empty space, and your own death.